# matplotlib figure inset whitespace

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm making a figure for that includes an inset. I cannot figure out how to get the whitespace on to be removed. I've tried using `tight_sublot()` but it still leaves whitespace near the inset that I'd like to remove. Any suggestions?

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import silicon2_data

data = silicon2_data.out

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

for temperature in data:
    xs = temperature[:,0]
    ys = temperature[:,1]
    zs = temperature[:,2]
    ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs)
ax.set_zbound(0, 1.4)

ax.set_xlabel(r'$2\theta$ (degrees)')
ax.set_ylabel('Temperature (K)')
ax.set_zlabel(r'Intensity ($10^5$cts/sec)')
#inset
ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.15, 0.62, 0.25, 0.25])

ax2.plot(data[3,:,0], data[3,:,2],'bo')
ax2.plot(data[7,:,0], data[7,:,2],'rx')

ax2.legend(('16K', '18K'), loc=0, fontsize ='small')
ax2.set_ybound(0, 1.4)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This is roughly what I'm trying to make:

[image]

Comment: can you post a picture elsewhere, add the link here and then explain exactly what you want?

Comment: Here is a link to roughly what I'm trying to make:http://web.mit.edu/dillon/www/python/figure_3.png

Answer (score 0):

After calling

```
fig = plt.figure()
```

you can adjust characteristics of the subplots before adding them with `fig.add_subplot()` by using pyplot's `subplots_adjust()` method. For your purposes, you might try

```
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.05)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.05)
```

where the number is the fraction of the figure's width or height.

Comment: This doesn't fix my problem. I'd like to ultimately have a figure that is as tight as possible (i.e. no extra whitespace.) Maybe the issue is that I'm explicitly locating the second axes as I want it to be an inset?

Comment: @dillon did you try setting `hspace` and `wspace` to 0?

Comment: @dillon, also, can you post a picture of the results you're getting, and a mockup of what you're trying to achieve? It's kind of hard to visualize without any data to put into your code.

Comment: Yes, I have tried setting hspace and wspace to 0. I am still having additional whitespace to the left of my figure that I'd like to remove.